# математическая задача c++

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Вывести на экран таблицу значений функции Y(x) и ее разложения в ряд S(x) для x, изменяющегося от a до b с шагом h = (b – a)/10:

[image: первый столбец -номер задания, второй - а, третий - b, четвертый - x, пятый - число циклов, шестой - y]

как сказал преподаватель, после компиляции столбцы y и x должны быть примерно одинаковы, но они не сходятся, жду помощи.
Скрин вывода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

static long float fac(int n)
{
    long float r = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
        r *= i;
    return r;
}
int main() {
    double x=0, y, s=0, h, b = 1, a = 0.1; 
    short int k;
    short int n = 1;
    h = (b - a) / 10;

        for (k = 0; k != 80; k++) {
            x += h;
            y = 2 * (pow(cos(x), 2) - 1);
            do{
                s += pow(-1, n) * pow(2 * x, 2 * n) / fac(2 * n);
                n += 1;
                if (x > 1) {
                    return 0;
                }
            } while (n < k);
            cout << "x: " << setw(15) << x;
            cout << "       y(x): " << setw(15) << y ;
            cout << "       s(x): " << s << endl;
        }

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сам подход с явным вычислением факториала и степени мне не нравится, так что я лучше покажу с нуля, как это лучше сделать. Чтобы понять — начните с рассмотрения отношения соседних членов ряда.

Да, и метка `рекурсия` тут совершенно ни при чем, рекурсии у вас никакой нет...

```
int main()
{
    double b = 1, a = 0.1, eps = 0.00000001;

    for(double x = a; x <= b; x += (b-a)/10)
    {
        double t = 1, s = 0;
        for(int n = 0; abs(t) > eps; ++n)
            s += t *= -2*x*x/(2*n+1)/(n+1);
        double c = cos(x);

        cout << "x: " << setw(15) << x;
        cout << "       y(x): " << setw(15) << 2*(c*c-1);
        cout << "       s(x): " << s << endl;
    }
}
```

См. результаты тут: https://ideone.com/gfEUbk